# Security permissions of an OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to customize the Security section in the properties of a new OU. But I really can't find anything that can modify that section directly. Basically I need to add to that section two groups, remove one and be able to modify the permissions of each group (allow or deny). 
I think that I can access the permissions with

```
(Get-Acl $DistinguishedName).Access |
  Format-List identityreference, accesscontroltype, activedirectoryrights
```

But don't know how to modify them.

Comment: You need to create new ACL and apply it with Set-ACL command.

This script here show how to do it : 

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-Custom-Permissions-on-69af151c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify AD ACLs the same way you modify other ACLs. You just need to use the correct AccessRule type ([`ActiveDirectoryAccessRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this case).

```
$dn  = 'CN=foo,OU=bar,DC=example,DC=org'
$sid = (Get-ADGroup -Identity 'groupname').SID

$acl = Get-Acl -Path "AD:$dn"

$ace = New-Object DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid,
         'ReadProperty', 'Allow', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
         'All', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)  # remove inheritance
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)

Set-Acl -Path "AD:$dn" -AclObject $acl
```

If you want to modify existing ACEs you need to copy ACEs you want to preserve, re-create ACEs you want to change with modified settings, remove all existing ACEs (by changing the second argument of [`SetAccessRuleProtection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `$false`), then add the new, copied, and modified ACEs.

Comment: That way I can finally add new ACEs, but could not figure out how to remove ACEs, do you have any sugestions? I dont want to break the inheritance that already exists.

Comment: @Dimo Use `RemoveAccessRule()` (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx)). The handling is always the same, only the ACE type differs depending on which kind of object you're handling. You can either construct an ACE matching the one you want to remove as described in that article, or you can select rules matching specific criteria and remove those, e.g. `$acl.Access | ? { $_.IdentityReference -eq 'DOMAIN\username' } | % { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) }`. Note that you cannot remove inherited ACLs without breaking inheritance, though.

Comment: Worked like a charm. After a lot of search your answer was perfect. The ACE that I wanted to remove was the one that protects the OU from being deleted accidently, which I resolved by setting `-ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion` to `$false` when creating a new OU.

Comment: Is there a way to set InheritanceFlags and PropagationFlags when creating the ACE or after?

`$identity = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -eq "Name"}).SID
$adRights = 'CreateChild, DeleteChild'
$type = 'Allow'
$objectType = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
$inheritanceType = 'All'
$inheritedObjectType = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

$ace = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $identity,$adRights,$type,$objectType,$inheritanceType,$inheritedObjectType`

By default (I think) the `InheritanceFlags` are `ContainerInherit` and `PropagationFlags` are `None`.

Comment: @Dimo inheritance and propagation flags are set indirectly via the `inheritanceType` parameter (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectorysecurityinheritance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for possible values).